Loading the address of a label with LDR reg,=symbol fails to link in a shared library with clang
I'm trying to build x265 code on ARMv7 FreeBSD. The code includes several ARMv7-specific .S files, which are all compiled like this (note the -fPIC flag):
/usr/bin/c++ -mcpu=native -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=vfp -marm -fPIC -DPIC -c /var/tmp/mi/usr/home/mi/ports/multimedia/x265/work/source/common/arm/ipfilter8.S -o ipfilter8.S.o

However, when all of the object-files are being linked into the target library, there are multiple errors for each of the assembly-files listing the multiple functions defined in each one:
/usr/bin/c++ -fPIC -pipe -O3 -fstack-protector-strong -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -O3 -fstack-protector-strong -fno-strict-aliasing   -DNDEBUG  -fstack-protector-strong  -L/var/tmp/mi/usr/home/mi/ports/multimedia/x265/work/10bit -L/var/tmp/mi/usr/home/mi/ports/multimedia/x265/work/12bit -Wl,-Bsymbolic,-znoexecstack -shared -Wl,-soname,libx265.so.209 -o libx265.so.209 asm.S.o cpu-a.S.o mc-a.S.o sad-a.S.o pixel-util.S.o ssd-a.S.o blockcopy8.S.o ipfilter8.S.o dct-a.S.o encoder/CMakeFiles/encoder.dir/analysis.cpp.o encoder/CMakeFiles/encoder.dir/search.cpp.o encoder/CMakeFiles/encoder.dir/bitcost.cpp.o encoder/CMakeFiles/encoder.dir/motion.cpp.o encoder/CMakeFiles/encoder.dir/slicetype.cpp.o encoder/CMakeFiles/encoder.dir/frameencoder.cpp.o encoder/CMakeFiles/encoder.dir/framefilter.cpp.o encoder/CMakeFiles/encoder.dir/level.cpp.o encoder/CMakeFiles/encoder.dir/nal.cpp.o encoder/CMakeFiles/encoder.dir/sei.cpp.o encoder/CMakeFiles/encoder.dir/sao.cpp.o encoder/CMakeFiles/encoder.dir/entropy.cpp.o encoder/CMakeFiles/encoder.dir/dpb.cpp.o encoder/CMakeFiles/encoder.dir/ratecontrol.cpp.o encoder/CMakeFiles/encoder.dir/reference.cpp.o encoder/CMakeFiles/encoder.dir/encoder.cpp.o encoder/CMakeFiles/encoder.dir/api.cpp.o encoder/CMakeFiles/encoder.dir/weightPrediction.cpp.o common/CMakeFiles/common.dir/arm/asm-primitives.cpp.o common/CMakeFiles/common.dir/primitives.cpp.o common/CMakeFiles/common.dir/pixel.cpp.o common/CMakeFiles/common.dir/dct.cpp.o common/CMakeFiles/common.dir/lowpassdct.cpp.o common/CMakeFiles/common.dir/ipfilter.cpp.o common/CMakeFiles/common.dir/intrapred.cpp.o common/CMakeFiles/common.dir/loopfilter.cpp.o common/CMakeFiles/common.dir/constants.cpp.o common/CMakeFiles/common.dir/cpu.cpp.o common/CMakeFiles/common.dir/version.cpp.o common/CMakeFiles/common.dir/threading.cpp.o common/CMakeFiles/common.dir/threadpool.cpp.o common/CMakeFiles/common.dir/wavefront.cpp.o common/CMakeFiles/common.dir/bitstream.cpp.o common/CMakeFiles/common.dir/yuv.cpp.o common/CMakeFiles/common.dir/shortyuv.cpp.o common/CMakeFiles/common.dir/picyuv.cpp.o common/CMakeFiles/common.dir/common.cpp.o common/CMakeFiles/common.dir/param.cpp.o common/CMakeFiles/common.dir/frame.cpp.o common/CMakeFiles/common.dir/framedata.cpp.o common/CMakeFiles/common.dir/cudata.cpp.o common/CMakeFiles/common.dir/slice.cpp.o common/CMakeFiles/common.dir/lowres.cpp.o common/CMakeFiles/common.dir/piclist.cpp.o common/CMakeFiles/common.dir/predict.cpp.o common/CMakeFiles/common.dir/scalinglist.cpp.o common/CMakeFiles/common.dir/quant.cpp.o common/CMakeFiles/common.dir/deblock.cpp.o common/CMakeFiles/common.dir/scaler.cpp.o common/CMakeFiles/common.dir/ringmem.cpp.o common/CMakeFiles/common.dir/temporalfilter.cpp.o dynamicHDR10/CMakeFiles/dynamicHDR10.dir/json11/json11.cpp.o dynamicHDR10/CMakeFiles/dynamicHDR10.dir/JsonHelper.cpp.o dynamicHDR10/CMakeFiles/dynamicHDR10.dir/metadataFromJson.cpp.o dynamicHDR10/CMakeFiles/dynamicHDR10.dir/SeiMetadataDictionary.cpp.o dynamicHDR10/CMakeFiles/dynamicHDR10.dir/api.cpp.o  -lx265_10bit  -lx265_12bit  -lpthread  -lmd  -lrt  -ldl
...
ld: error: relocation R_ARM_ABS32 cannot be used against local symbol; recompile with -fPIC
>>> defined in ipfilter8.S.o
>>> referenced by ipfilter8.S.o:(x265_interp_8tap_vert_sp_4x4_neon)

Using g++ seems to work, but c++ (which is clang-16 here) fails as above... What am I missing?
This seems to be the minimal example. With the /tmp/soo.S being:
.arch           armv7-a

.section .rodata
.align 4

g_lumaFilter:
.word 0,0,0,0,0,0,64,64,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

    ldr             r12, =g_lumaFilter

Attempt to create the shared library with clang's c++:
c++ -shared -o /tmp/libt.so /tmp/foo.S
ld: error: relocation R_ARM_ABS32 cannot be used against local symbol; recompile with -fPIC
>>> defined in /tmp/foo-9defb5.o
>>> referenced by /tmp/foo-9defb5.o:(.rodata+0x104)
c++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

But using g++ works...
Adding .global g_lumaFilter before the label doesn't help for clang.

This is hand-written asm, so there's nothing to recompile from.  (And -fPIC probably doesn't matter for .S files, only C++ source files since it's a code-gen option.  That's the case for x86-64 where some relocation types are similarly incompatible with linking into a shared lib.)  I assume x265 does build all its C++ source files with -fPIC, and it doesn't hurt for hand-written asm, but probably the only solution is to fix the code, not different build options.  So we need to know which source line this relocation came from.

The assembly-sources are all here. x265 developers seem to be using GCC and don't even know, there is a problem with clang, it seems...

Yes, I'm aware x265 is open-source.  For this to be a good Stack Overflow question, it can't just be "how do I fix x265 to work with clang on ARM", with the only source code being a link to the source tree and the name of a function to look for.  You can report it upstream to x265 with a report like this, but to make a good question here with any general applicability, you're going to need to make a [mcve] of asm source that reproduces this.  Should only need half a dozen source lines of asm or less, maybe just .syntax unified, a label, and an instruction referencing that label.

Also, since relocation details can depend on the OS, I'm guessing this is ARM Linux with ELF object files?  I don't think macOS ever supported 32-bit ARMv7.

Though it is, most likely, going to be the same for Linux, I'm using FreeBSD/armv7, actually...

Ok, there we go, that's a proper [mcve] of loading the address of a local label.  Does it link properly with .global g_lumaFilter added, to check that the behaviour matches what the error message seems to be implying, that being local is part of the problem?

With .global g_lumaFilter added where? I tried inserting that line right after the .align 4 and the error is still present...

Before or after g_lumaFilter: is fine.  It's common to put it before the label that actually defines the symbol position, so if clang was going to work right for one order but not the other, before is the most normal place to put a .global directive.  That's a very interesting data point, telling us that the problem is not that the label used in the source code isn't global.  I'm guessing the ABS32 relocation it's complaining about is that label, as a 32-bit word in a literal pool holding the address. The ldr reg,=val pseudo insn puts val in a literal pool and emits a PC-relative ldr

Whether before or after the g_lumaFilter, I still get ld: error: relocation R_ARM_ABS32 cannot be used against symbol 'g_lumaFilter'; recompile with -fPIC from clang and /usr/bin/ld, that come with the OS. The g++ -- and the binutils-provided /usr/local/bin/ld -- are more forgiving.

Ok, so the error message is different, dropping the word local when it's not a local symbol.  It's just helping you identify which symbol; saying local is useful in case there's a global symbol of the same name.  So it's not implying that the symbol visibility was part of the problem.  (Which didn't make much sense anyway.)

FWIW, gnu assembler seems to emit R_ARM_RELATIVE which is probably why it works.

Place the luma filter in .text and use the adr instruction.  See: Getting label to a register  gcc has decided that .rodata and .text are in the same output section.  It is a default like text: { *.(text); *(.rodata) }.  Maybe clang has different ideas.  You can definitely use some linker tricks to solve it as well.  The benefit of .rodata is related to data caching.  Interspersing with .text might put some code in the data cache.  Unless you pay attention to data layout, this won't matter.

@Jester, artless-noise, you're confusing me... Perhaps, you can make a proper answer for me to try -- and then accept? Thanks!

In this case, it looks like the 'luma filter' will be cache friendly, so only collisions would be a concern and that is a weak weak weak argument.  Change .rodata to .text  change ldr r12,=g_LumaFilter to adr r12,g_LumaFilter.  I don't like cut and paste spoon feed answers.  I prefer when poster understand things...

@artlessnoise, this lets my artifical example compile/link, but the real code does not even compile: error: out of range pc-relative fixup value         adr r12, g_lumaFilter

If you put the constant into .text it might work if you keep the ldr.

Change line 28 and remove line 47 in ipfilt8.S.  ldr will work but it is inefficient. You create .ltorg and two loads.  If the adr works the file should not have relocations.  Also the poster is compiling with 'PIC' and ldr is not PIC, anticipating the next question because they refuse to understand the task.  Also, you can use clang and link with gas assembler output.  That is another path.

@artlessnoise, I'm not seeking to learn ARMv7 assembly -- just want to resolve the clang-specific problem on FreeBSD, where clang is the default compiler. Using gas would be a nasty requirement, because that'd mean having to install binutils first... I tried just what you suggested before -- as well as modifying the movrel-macro in the asm.S to emit adr. That's, how I got the compile error in my earlier response. Omitting that last step -- keeping the ldr -- compiles, but the original linking error stays...

Use adrl instead of adr, then; if it is still failing, you need to look at a map file as the code sections are too big.  Try reading the Q/A I referenced.  Getting a label to a register.  Using ldr rx,=xxxx is wrong with PIC.  It may compile, but it won't execute (correctly) upon relocation.

Also, the 'asm.S' is incorrect.  They use the ldr rX,=xxx when compiling with PIC.  This is broken.  Consider submitting a patch and reference the Getting a label to a register.  Also, the technical people who authored it, should understand the issue and my points, even if you don't.  The value is that as you update to a newer version of the library, the upstream will have the fix.

I know the benefits of submitting an upstream patch -- and have submitted hundreds in the last 30 years, most recently -- today,  based on an earlier question. :-) But I need to get it from somewhere -- maybe, you can include one (even if partial) in your answer? (P.S. adrl is rejected by the compiler as invalid instruction, did you mean: adr?.)

https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0041/c/Babcjaii  adr is limited to 1020 bytes of offset.  The adrl is a longer offset version.  You need to update your tooling.  https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/24724 or move the filters closer to the code.  Search for 'MYADRL' macro which will work with LLVM assembler.

If I'm forcing the users, who seek to build x265 on their armv7 machines, to install a new compiler, I may as well install gcc -- as that's, what the upstream developers themselves are using. Is there really no way do this with the clang-16, that comes with FreeBSD-14 "out of the box"?

Again, search for the MYADRL macro, in the link provided.    .macro MYADRL reg:req, label:req     add \reg, pc, #((\label - .) & 0xff00)      add \reg, \reg, #((\label - .) - ((\label - .) & 0xff00)) - 4             .endm  It is a variant of option 4, i posted in the other question.

@MikhailT.: If you don't want to learn ARM assembly, asking a Stack Overflow question about it was not the best approach.  Stack Overflow isn't about having other people do work for you like fix upstream codebases, it's about learning and sharing knowledge for people writing code like the code you're asking about.  If you want someone else to come up with a fix for x265 on ARM clang without you having to understand how/why it works, an x265 bug report or mailing-list message would be your best bet.  The necessary changes turned out not to be just a compiler option. :/

My question was about clang vs. GNU, @PeterCordes. I have filed a bug report against x265 too, but I'm well aware, the code's been written a while ago and will not be fixed soon. What the required changes turned out to be was not known, when the question was asked, was it? Generally, SO has a problem treating askers -- the onus is placed on them to ask a good question, rather than on the responders to give a good answer...

Well sure, it didn't hurt to ask.  I was replying re: you getting annoyed with people for expecting you to know / learn ARM assembly / toolchain stuff when it turned out there wasn't an easy fix.  An answer to this question could have explained exactly why that code didn't work in a shared library for clang but did for GAS, e.g. different relocation types as Jester mentioned.  As well as linking the current duplicate re: code that could work on both.

the onus is placed on them to ask a good question - That requirement has to exist, otherwise people would flood SO with low-effort low-quality questions, and there are a lot of people in the world.  The question volume is already high relative to the amount of time experts have to answer well.
This question does seem good to me, with the MCVE as is.  Focusing it more towards "please port x265's asm to clang for me" would be less good, although it's still a small enough MCVE that posting a working version of that which works with ARM Clang is not unreasonable to hope for.

Maybe this should even be reopened if current Clang still doesn't support adrl, @artlessnoise, so a working example for ARM Clang can be posted for cases where some code wants to load some constants, considering the tradeoffs imposed by a toolchain limitation.

My annoyance, to use a car analogy was that of person wondering, how to get in a toyota, where people have no problem getting in a honda, being expected to learn intricacies of engine design :) Yes, people should try asking good questions, but answers -- good, or, at least usable -- are more important. Look at my two questions today, you participated in both: one has a good answer by a newbie -- not you, a decorated veteran. Though you had an answer, you were more concerned in finding a duplicate. And the other has no answers at all, just 20+ comments telling me, to do better...

@PeterCordes, I added information in the comment of the referenced duplicate.  The ARM compilers were supporting adrl as does gcc and keil.  Also ARM documents adrl.  ARM7 support is obviously not a concern for clang developers.  I think Clang should support it.  Also, the referenced macro is not perfect in the clang ticket (but can be used to handle individual cases).  Root cause is that the x264 library has an ARM bug related to relocatable code.  It is not relocatable even with gcc (but it does build).  Clang section selection is another complication in this Q/A.

Also, a closed duplicate is linked to the close reference and remains visible to google and other search engines for those interested in these particular details.

Finally, there are so many solutions to this particular issue that is is really opinion based in the current form.  Do you fix x264, do you fix clang or do you use gcc tooling?  The issues have been enumerated, but they are all separate things.  I really can't understand why clang/llvm can not include a gas (binutils) that is compatible.

LLVM has a different license from binutils. But is not adrl a macro of some sort -- rather than an actual CPU-instruction? I got the thing to work using the MYADRLSUB-macro from here. It compiles now and passes its own self-tests, but I'm not sure, how comprehensive those are... Once the FreeBSD port is upgraded, we might get some real life feedback... Or not...

Yes, LLVM and binutils have different license.  But those are the tools, not the output.  So if you compile x264 'C' code will LLVM and  assemble the 'S' files with gas, the resulting binary is still whatever license x264 has.  I am just saying this is a way to avoid porting all the assembler to LLVM syntax, which the distro should consider?  Wouldn't that save us all pain?  If llvm supported adrl, it would make PIC/PIE mods easy (which is what FreeBSD wants for ASLR?).  Good luck, I support what you are doing, but I don't think it is a good Q/A for stack overflow.  The issues are complex.

People building a port would need to build the additional tools too. Which is possible, but should be avoided, if possible...

btw, I mean to add gas (binutils) to the FreeBSD packages.  They should not need to rebuild the tools.  I thought FreeBSD was like Gentoo.  It is common that open source projects will have 'gas' based source (as you encountered).  In order to work around or upgrade to LLVM tooling, a gas based binutils would make it easier for the entire FreeBSD community.  So, I think you misunderstood what I meant.  Ie, porters do not rebuild clang/llvm?  So, I am saying give a binutils the same status, compatible with the clang/llvm tooling.
